# Why does the Maven Repositories view in Eclipse M2E not know of all the artifacts on the repo?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have two repos set in my settings.xml for a particular ecosystem.  One is a "release" repo, and the other is a "snapshot" repo.

My build references both release and snapshot artifacts from those repos.  The command line build currently works fine, and Eclipse has no red marks.

I want to understand what I'm seeing in the "Maven Repositories" view, and the results I see when I enter a string in the "Enter groupId, artifactId, ..." field in the dialog (titled "Select Dependency") when I click "Add" in the "Dependencies" tab of the pom.xml editor.

I use as a sample a particular artifact that I'm getting from the snapshot repo, so it obviously has a SNAPSHOT version.  When I look at the "Maven Repositories" view, and in the "Global Repositories" section, I see both the "release" and "snapshot" repos.  I can right-click on the snapshot repo and select "Copy URL" and then browse that repo in my web browser.  I can navigate to the groupid folder, then the artifactid folder, and then the versions.  I see the artifact and version I'm using in the build.

If I go back to the "Maven Repositories" view and click the arrow next to the repo name, it shows me the first level of folders in that repo.  In the web browser, in that folder, I see the following:

- org
- archetype-catalog.xml
- archetype-catalog.xml.md5
- archetype-catalog.xml.sha1

In Eclipse, I see this:

- org
- sitebuildsettings

I think it's reasonable that I don't see the catalog files in the Eclipse view, but I don't know what that "sitebuildsettings" folder is that I see in the Eclipse view.

I then go on and navigate into the "org" folder on both the web browser and the Eclipse view.  Both of them have the same next level folder at that point, so I navigate into that on both.

At this point, there's a huge difference.  In the Eclipse view, there's only one folder, called "controller", not that it matters.  That folder is also seen in the web browser, but there are also several dozen other folders in the web browser view, one of which contains the artifact I'm using for this sample.

If I instead navigate into the "release" repo in the "Maven Repositories" view, this seems to be much closer to what I also see in the web browser, although it's hard to tell if it's identical.  I did verify that I can find the artifact in question, but of course I don't see the version I'm looking for, because this repo doesn't have snapshots.

Unsurprisingly, when I try to add a dependency through the "Add" gui, if I enter the name of my artifact in the search field, I find it in the list, but it only shows the versions I saw in the release repo, not the ones from the snapshot repo.

I will emphasize again, my build is running fine, and Eclipse has no red marks.  The build is obviously able to FIND this snapshot artifact.  It's likely getting it now from my local cache, but also note that I wasn't even using this particular version before yesterday.  I was using older versions.  I had updated the pom.xml to reflect the new desired version and ran a build, and it worked on the first try.

The only thing that's confused is the Maven Repositories view, and the resulting indexing in the "Add" dialog.